# Google Play Pre-Launch Report Getting Security and Trust Anomalous Permission Usage issue on play billing library

Tags: android, google-play, play-billing-library, prelaunch

When Uploaded App in Google play getting privacy issue in pre-launch report, how to get resolve this issue.

[image]

Comment: This is true, I tried removing 'com.android.vending.BILLING' from manifest and rebuilding the project. As noted in: https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/release-notes#release-1_0

Still, the final merged AndroidManifest.xml contains this permission.

Comment: Looks like new auto review feature from google play store team

Answer (score 0):

this is as a result of automatic comparison with similar apps, if you are sure that you are using IAP correctly do not worry about it and continue and way.

Comment: Interesting that this "warning" displaying like Error with red color :-/

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed this by researching merged manifest, text file which located in `app\build\intermediates\manifest_merge_blame_file\{flavorBuildType}\manifest-merger-blame-{flavor}-{buildType}-report.txt`

In this file we can see all permissions which are available in our compiled build + library which is bring this permission to merged permission list.

You can easily find which library brings permission which invoke the warning from play market:
[image]

In my case it was **unused library**, so as a result I've just **removed unused library**.

---

Also anouther solution - **check newest version of the library** and try to update (and check permissions with new library), for example in oldest version of dji sdk there is a lot of system permissions, but in new version the list was cleanuped.

---

Also you can remove the permission from thrird party libraries like:

```
<uses-permission
        android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING"
        tools:node="remove" />
```

But in this case ^ some part of functionality can be restricted.

Answer (score 0):

> Clean and Rebuild your project and **Add this line in your Manifest
> file**.
>
> ```
> <uses-permission
>         android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING"
>         tools:node="remove" />
> ```

***Furthermore,***

1. **Delete and Clear all the Caches** from the Users Profile folders located in your system `.android` and `.gradle` Located: `C:\Users\DELL\.android`
2. **Update and Download the latest SDK** from the SDK Manager and delete the older, unused ones.
3. **Update Gradle Wrapper.**

   `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.3-all.zip`

Comment: In my case (using Xamarin Android) adding 'tools:node="remove"' did remove the issue in the pre-lauch report. However it also made the purchase option unusable in my published app (error message: 'This version of the application is not configured for billing through google play'). 
So for now I removed the line and will keep the issue in the pre-lauch report.